# Incrementing String by an amount

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to take any string from command line argument and increment it by an amount taken by another command line argument.

For example - `Python 2`

Result - `onPyth`

```
    import sys
def rotate(a,b):
    ns = a[-1] + a[0:-1]
    return ns

def main():
    a = sys.argv[1]
    b = sys.argv[2]
    print(rotate(a,int(b)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit - Both answers work, Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way.

```
def rotate(a, b):
    ns = a[-b:] + a[:-b]
    return ns

rotate('Python', 2)

# 'onPyth'
```

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be achieved by python String [slicing.](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)

```
   def rotate(a,b):
        ns = a[-b:] + a[:-b]
        return ns
    print(rotate(a,b))
```

The rotate method gets the substring from the last `n` indexes and adds from the beginning until the length of the string minus `n`, which is obviously the rest of the string.

Happy Coding!

Comment: The `len(a)` is redundant here.